# String manipulation and formatting issue (parsed string from JSON needs manipulation /w JAVA - java classes included)

Tags: java, json, string, maven

So going back to my JSON example with Java. I would like to be able to do the following: (before asking my question will introduce the problem)
I got the following JSON File:

```
x
```

In order to parse all this information into Java, 2 classes are needed: Manager + the main method:

The Manager Class:

```
x
```

And the main method:

```
x
```

Also the org.json library needs to be imported into the project.  [org json jar](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/json/json/20141113/json-20141113.jar)

Upon executing, the following output is given:

```
Chris - 43 - Retail - HLF
John - 36 - Sales - FLS
Mark - 48 - TechSupport - HFO
```

Where H, L, F, S and O are personality types as follows:
H - hardworking
L - loyal 
F - funny
S - serious
O - outgoing

**My question is:** how would I be able to manipulate each of those strings "type" (HLF , FLS and HFO) in order to get an output like this:

```
Chris - hardworking - loyal - funny
John - funny - loyal - serious
Mark - hardworking - funny - outgoing
```

I am not entirely sure that my question has to do with string manipulation, I did some searching on the matter and I believe it does. (not sure though)

Any solutions/ideas/suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: have you considered using `EnumSet` for your personality types?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @GeorgeSimms I got it working using Titus's solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the `setType(...)` method of your `Manager` class to something like this:

```
 public void setType(String type) {
    type = type.replace("H", "hardworking ");
    type = type.replace("L", "loyal ");
    type = type.replace("F", "funny ");
    type = type.replace("S", "serious "); 
    type = type.replace("O", "outgoing ");
    this.type = type;
 }
```

Comment: Will try it and let you know how it went. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Really valuable.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe override toString() method in Manager class and use charAt() method which returns char at given position.

```
public class Manager
{
//...

@Override
public String toString()
{
    String result = "";
    if(type != null)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<type.length();++i)
        {
            char a = type.charAt(i);

            if(a == 'H')
            {
                result += " Hardworking";
            }
            //..
        }
    }

    return this.name + result;
}
}
```

and than you can do only:

```
Manager manager = new Manager();

//...code parsing from json
System.out.println(manager);
```

EDIT:
You can also save your personality types in final char:

```
private final static char HARDWORKING_TYPE = 'H';
```

and than use it insted literal:

```
if(a == HARDWORKING_TYPE)
```

it is better practise. You can also use enum type.

EDIT2:

It is not connected with main question, but you can also parse from json not using dummy "pure" object, but use annotations to map object. In this case you have to change your JSON library. Example:

http://software.danielwatrous.com/restful-java-servlet-serializing-tofrom-json-with-jackson/

Comment: Will give it a go and let you know how it went. Thanks.

Comment: I would like to thank you for the time spent in writing this solution. I got into it but using @Titus's idea I got it working the way I wanted to and a bit faster. Again, thank you.